# Using iGoogle Gadgets API with a custom website

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to use Google iGadget API with my ASP.NET website or it just can be used to develop gadgets for iGoogle portal only ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a compliant gadget container. Take a look at [Apache Shindig](http://shindig.apache.org/) for an open source example. Not sure if there's anything specifically for ASP.NET, though...

**UPDATE:** Looks like [Pesta](http://my6solutions.com/category/Pesta.aspx) might be a possibility.

Comment: Thanks for help but I believe that it suitable with me. I want something more generic

Comment: Maybe you need to explain in a little more detail how you're expecting it to work, then? In particular, what did you think would implement the API, if not a gadget container of some sort?

Also note that the API is a client-side JavaScript one, so the fact that the server-side is ASP.NET is somewhat orthogonal to what happens with the gadgets.

Comment: OK, can I use google's Gadget Container in my application.
Thanks